# How can I compile java programs in Sublime Text and have the output show up?

Tags: java, installation, std, sublimetext

I am trying to run Princeton Algorithm examples on Sublime Text instead of DrJava, but I am having two problems 1) Getting sublimetext to import the custom Princeton Java libraries (which are downloadable as .jar files) and 2) trouble getting the editor to compile and run the code in the output window.

Here is some example code:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;


public class Percolation {
    private boolean[][] grid;
    private final int d;
    private final int topSite;
    private final int bottomSite;
    private final WeightedQuickUnionUF topMap;
    private final WeightedQuickUnionUF map;
    private int numOpenSites;

    public Percolation(int n) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        grid = new boolean[n][n];
        d = n;
        topSite = n*n;
        bottomSite = n*n+1;
        numOpenSites = 0;
        map = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2); 
        topMap = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+1); 

    }

    private void checkParams(int i, int j) {
        if (i >= d || i < 0 || j >= d || j < 0) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
...
```

I get the error:
error: cannot find symbol
    private final WeightedQuickUnionUF topMap;

because the library is not imported

And for this code

```
public class Test {
    private boolean[][] grid;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Is 1,1 Open: Testing");       

    }
}
```

I can only compile the source, but no output is printed!

Comment: Sublime doesn't `import` anything; it just edits files for you. You need to do your own setup to tell the Java tools where to find the libraries you want to use. I believe your program doesn't run because you're probably using the built in Java build system, which only compiles the current file and doesn't run it.

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I'm seeing. What I ended up doing is using a command that incorporates the libraries and run from the terminal. In this case I run:

java-algs4 Percolation input40.txt

And it works

Comment: You can use custom build system

Comment: Thanks.. I found using the cli tools to compile and run works!